# How to disable splitting of chunks into different file with vuejs in webpack?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have laravel-vue stack for my project. While building with `mix` it splits codes into two main files

```
vendor.js
app.js
```

Apart from that there are around 60 files which gets created as chunks like

```
0.js
1.js
2.js
...

61.js
```

How to tell webpack to bind these chunks into single file. Does the webpack breaks into chunks for each new component in cue?

Comment: It would be great to see your webpack config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify how many chunks you want in your webpack configuration file (example is from a `vue.config.js` file) like this:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        minSize: 10000,
        maxSize: 250000,
      }
    }
  },
};
```

I don't know your filesize, but if you increase `maxSize` as needed, you can have a single file.

Comment: Added maxSize but still getting same result

Comment: It was affecting vendor related chunks, but those 1.js, 2.js, 3. js, they are still not getting affected by it.

Comment: You can also try LimitChunkCount plugin: 

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/